# Kinesis shard with many producers

Tags: amazon-kinesis, aws-iot

I need to collect data from lots of data sources (e.g., mobile phones). For example, 1,000 phones, each uploading a batch of 1MB every 20 minutes. I am thinking to use a Kinesis stream with a single shard to ingest the data (the total throughput is roughly 1MB/s). 
Would it make sense for the individual phones to directly access the Kinesis API, or should I put my own frontend (e.g., web server) in front? What would be the main limits/considerations to keep in mind when making this decision?

P.S. The alternative to use the AWS IoT infrastructure would be considerably more expensive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a web service that receives the data from your clients and will send them to Kinesis. This web server can use the Kinesis Producer Library (KPL) that offer best performance in terms of message rate delivery, timeout, policy retry and scalability. KPL can create many workers and can be tuned to optimize the message rate and not exceed the write limit imposed by Kinesys Shards.

Have every single client that sends data to kinesis could be an overkill in terms of performance, mainenantce costs and delivery.
What happen if a client start to sends data at high rate traffic? A shard has a rate limit for write operation (up to 1,000 Record/s, data write rate up to 1 MB/s). 
An 'aggressive' client could generate eccessive traffic and make a shard not responding for a while, and block all the other clients that send records that should be stored in the same shard.

Moreover, think about the delivery cost over thousands of clients. What happen if you want change the stream name? or change the accessID/ key? Or just switch from kinesis to kafka? You have to manage the update of thousands of clients.

With a web server, you can hide the complexity and make any change transparent to the client. You can think to run the web service directly in EC2. Have the producer directly in AWS should reduce the network latency. Moreover, you can take advantage of all the scalability/resiliency/fault tolerance features offered by AWS.